# Create right Jquery Array for Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

im dying with trying to create the right Datatable array.
I hope someone can assist me ! :)

Fill the Data array

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var test = [];
    object = results[i];
    console.log("className " + object.attributes.block_hash);
    tblData.push(["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"]);
}   


    $(".javascript-sourced").DataTable({
        data: [tblData],
        columns: [{
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            title: "Position"
        }, {
            title: "Office"
        }, {
            title: "Extn."
        }, {
            title: "Start date"
        }, {
            title: "Salary"
        }]
    })
```

Datatable SET - this is the original Data. Mine is just showing 1 Row. I know its a problem with populating the tblData array right...

```
        $(".javascript-sourced").DataTable({
        data: [
            ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
            ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
            ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
            ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
            ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
            ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
            ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
            ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
            ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
            ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
            ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
            ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
            ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"]
        ],
        columns: [{
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            title: "Position"
        }, {
            title: "Office"
        }, {
            title: "Extn."
        }, {
            title: "Start date"
        }, {
            title: "Salary"
        }]
    })
```

Comment: You have two options when populating a datatable with data (excluding ajax/html) - *either* use an array *or* use an object.  You're passing an array, but your `columns` definition indicates the data is expected to be an object, eg `data: [ { "Name":  "Tiger", "Position":"Architect" .. }]`

Comment: Just to add to what @freedomn-m says: If you have an array of arrays `var dataSrc = [ [...], [...], ... ];` as your JavaScript data source, then [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) is what you need. If you have an array of objects `var dataSrc = [ {...}, {...}, ... ];`, then the DataTable `columns` option also needs to specify the `data` keys to use - for example `{ data: 'name' }` as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html). This last example is for Ajax, but the principle is the same for your JavaScript-sourced data.